# unable to return a complex number in octave function

Tags: octave, complex-numbers

I have defined a function as follows:

```
function retval = nck (n, k)
  #print(n, k)
  p = 1;

  for i = 0:k-1
    p = p * (n - i);
  endfor

  final = p / factorial(k);

  if(isreal(final))
    retval = rats(final);
  else
    re = rats(real(final));
    im = rats(imag(final));
    retval = complex(re, im);
  endif
endfunction
```

When I invoke the function as follows, I get an error:

```
>> nck(i,2)
error: invalid conversion from string to real N-D array
error: called from
    nck at line 13 column 12
>>
```

I am passing a complex number as first argument. What is the correct way to write it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Octave, but a quick look at the documentation shows that `rats()` returns a string - so you are calling `complex()` with two strings.  Perhaps you wanted `rat()` instead?

Comment: both rat and rats return strings. if all you're interested in is how the output 'looks' like, you might be interested in `format rat` instead  (and do calculations in your function normally without any calls to `rats` etc)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to see the result as fractions instead of decimals, you can simply have a normal function like

```
function retval = nck (n, k)
  p = 1;
  for i = 0:k-1;   p = p * (n - i);   endfor
  retval = p / factorial(k);
endfunction
```

and then do `format rat` before calling it:

```
octave:1> format rat
octave:2> nck( i , 2 )
ans = -1/2 - 1/2i
```

If you want to work with fractions more 'natively', then perhaps you might be interested in the symbolic package:

```
octave:3> pkg load symbolic
octave:4> nck( sym(i), 2 )
ans = (sym)
  ⅈ⋅(-1 + ⅈ)
  ──────────
      2
```